sendmail works when I trigger the .ksh file manually in the server, but not when triggered from autosys
I am facing an issue where I have installed sendmail in my server.
and I have a script that reads a file which has the email details (FROM:, TO:, and body of email)
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t < path/myfile
When I trigger the script manually from server, I am able to receive the email perfectly fine.
But the same script when I trigger form autosys, I do not see any error in send mail, but email is not coming up.
when I checked maillog, I dont see an error. but I see size=0.
So, somehow the file seems to not get picked.
I am using same user, same profile and I have verified all permissions too.
Could anyone advise on the issue.
I am using same user, same profile and I have verified all permissions too. I dont see a difference.

assuming you mean that the "maillog size is zero", then the mail system didn't get started. What do you autosys logs say about that particular step? It's almost certainly a difference in the PATH env variable OR some other env var. Set up an autosys job that just performs set > autosys.set ; printenv > autosys.printenv and from the working cmd-line, the same idea, set >cmdline.set ; printenv > cmdline.printenv and then diff autosys.set cmdline.set etc. Good luck.

I do not see any major difference in the env output.
Also I have used a blank .profile with my user and just tested a simple script using sendmail command. Still I have the same issue

I would expect sendmail logs it's activity somewhere (or can be configured to do so). See what you can find there, and I would expect that a command from /usr/sbin would need to run as an escalated user (root or someother privledged group) AND should be writing error messages to something like dsmg or other system level logging, but I'm not an expert on that. See what you can find there. Good luck.

I think it might help if you flag this for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved to [unix.se] AND add some helpful tags (sendmail, linux, sudo, logging (dmsg or other) ) .

Also look at man sendmail and see if your versions have any debugging or verbose modes and/or the ability to specify exactly the /path/to/mySenmail.log.
